# Rendering ERB in models: "no implicit conversion of ERB into String"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am rendering an ASCII map that looks like the following:[image: ASCII map, is it not so pretty?].

I want the asterisk in the map, which represents a character, to be red. Right now this characters asterisk is being assigned to its location as follows:

```
  def mark_character_coordinates
    WORLD.terrain[@character.y_coordinate][@character.x_coordinate][0][0] = "*"
  end
```

I want my characters location on the map (the asterisk) to render as red. My idea is to try to wrap the asterisk in a span and give it an id. Then go into my CSS and make ID color red. My problem is I am not sure how to insert ERB into the model and have it render as such in the view. After reading similar problems on stackoverflow, this is the closest I got:

```
  def mark_character_coordinates
    WORLD.terrain[@character.y_coordinate][@character.x_coordinate][0][0]
      = ERB.new("<span>*</span>")
  end
```

**What should I do? How do I insert ERB into a variable in the model and have it render accordingly in the view?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and easiest way to do this is to use JQuery. First, put the ASCII map inside a div with `id="ascii-map"` in your template. Then switch to the front-end. Once the DOM is fully loaded, you can parse the ASCII map, look for the asterisk, and then wrap it in a span element that has red color defined for its font.

In your CSS:

```
.red-font {
    color: red;
}
```

Then, some JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text = $('#ascii-map').html();
    var textWithRed = text.replace("*", "<span class='red-font'>*</span>");
    $('#ascii-map').html(textWithRed);
});
```

I test this and confirmed that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well... you're breaking MVC pretty badly, so that's one thing. Other than that though, do you need ERB for this? You're not embedding ruby at all. Why not just have it as a string?

i.e

```
def mark_character_coordinates
  WORLD.terrain[@character.y_coordinate][@character.x_coordinate][0][0] = "<span>*</span>"
end
```